# Fortify : Null dereference for Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, fortify

I am getting Null Dereference issue in fortify when I have following code in Java 8:

```
String name = statusList.stream()
    .map(s -> s.getNodeName())
    .filter(n -> n.equalsIgnoreCase(temName))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
 String parentName = name;
 if (parentName == null)
 {
    // if null code
 }
 else {
    // Not Null code
 }
```

I am validating if the value is `null` or not. Why do I still get an error? How can I fix this to satisfy fortify needs?

***UPDATE :***

I tried to get the stack trace but there nothing much,

I see this error too : `Assigned null : null (on orElse(null))`

***UPDATE 2:***

This is what I see. there is not big stack trace :

[image]

Comment: How about sharing the Exception...

Comment: Are you sure the Node Name property from your `.map` call is not null? I'm guessing it is complaining about the Stream, not the subsequent code.

Comment: To ensure `null`-safety it's better to flip equals and use `n->temName.equalsIgnoreCase(n)` as a predicate if the `temName` is known to be not `null`. You can simplify it as `temName::equalsIgnoreCase`. Otherwise, you should pass `null` as an argument to `equalsIgnoreCase`. And make sure the `statusList ` and `s` are also not `null`.

Comment: Use Java 8 Optional.

Comment: @DebadattaMishra The OP is already using `Optional`, that is what `findFirst()` returns.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the OP is receiving it but not *using* it. Using it would imply not calling `.orElse(null)`, followed by a `null` test but rather using, e.g. `isPresent()` in the first place.

Comment: @Holger Sure, but the suggestion by Debadatta by itself makes no suggestion, because they are already using `Optional`.

Comment: I have to agree with @Holger here... `orElse(null)` is a definite code smell and defeats the entire point of an `Optional` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need the exact `null`? You can use `isPresent()`

```
Optional<String> optionalName = statusList.stream()
    .map(s -> s.getNodeName())
    .filter(Objects::notNull) // to avoid nulls in comparation
    .filter(n -> n.equalsIgnoreCase(temName)) // I assume temName is not null
    .findFirst();

if (name.isPresent()) {
//not null code
} else {
//null code
}
```